# Compile tests with SBT and package them to be run later

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, integration-testing, sbt

Im working with SBT and Play! Framework. Currently we have a commit stage in our pipeline where we publish to artifactory our binaries. The binaries are generated with the dist task. The pipeline then runs smoke and acceptance tests that are written in scala. They are run with sbt.

What I want to do is to compile the smoke and acceptance tests as well as the binary and publish them to artifactory. That will allow the pipeline to download these binaries (the test suites) and run them, instead of recompiling them every time, which takes a long time.

I tried sbt test:compile which generates the jar, but then I cant find a way to run the tests.

Comment: What do you mean by "pipeline" exactly? Does the "pipeline" refer to a separate build server, like Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, we have a deployment pipeline managed by Jenkins. What it does is it downloads the code whenever someone pushes to master, runs tests on it and if successful, builds the binary with the dist task. Then it proceeds to publish it to Artifactory.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just run both the build and the test on the same build node, both using sbt. Also, my tests take far longer  to run than to compile, so I'm surprised that yours are the reverse.

Comment: Well we are doing that, sort of: In the same node we build I run the unit tests. Then my Jenkins communicates to the company's Jenkins and has it deploy the binary in QA environments. Then it communicates back and we proceed testing. Its in this step that we run the smoke tests with 'sbt smoke:tests'. This is the slow step. Because the jenkins job downloads the code again, sbt updates the ivy repositories, builds the binaries and five minutes later, runs a test suite that takes 7 secs, which is the smoke test. Its this step that I want to short-circuit. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

sbt dont publish test in artifacts

```
publishArtifact in GlobalScope in Test:== false
```

source: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/a7413f6415687f32e6365598680f3bb8545c46b5/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1118

this is how to enable it

```
// enable publishing the jar produced by `test:package`
publishArtifact in (Test, packageBin) := true

// enable publishing the test API jar
publishArtifact in (Test, packageDoc) := true

// enable publishing the test sources jar
publishArtifact in (Test, packageSrc) := true
```

source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts

run the test

```
scala -classpath pipeline.jar classpath scalatest-<version>.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -p compiled_tests
```

where `pipeline.jar` is the test artifact you receive from the pipeline

or you can setup a test projet via sbt

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html

Comment: So I actually did manage to get that. What Im generating with the test:package task is a jar. Now Im having trouble running it. It says it cant find the main class. Whats the main class of my whole test suite?

Comment: Hi Guillaume. Actually I could never get it working with ScalaTest because Im using Specs2. Im going to check how that runner works and get back to you.

Comment: I got it working with specs2. The following command works: "java $* -cp $classpath specs2.junitxml test.acceptance.LocationAcceptanceSpec" where classpath is the variable defined in the run script when running the dist task