# Running tests from jar with "sbt testOnly" in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

As part of a CI setup the very first step is to create a package/jar using SBT `dist`. The following steps are to run unit, integration and functional tests with the `dist`-created jar.

Is it possible to do that with SBT?

Normally I use `sbt testOnly "Unit.*"`, but that works in the context of a project. I can't find any documentation showing how to do this when there is already a jar.

I'm using ScalaTest and I know there is a runner for it I could use http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner. But using SBT would be simpler, if that is possible.

As an example, something like this is what I am looking for:

```
sbt testOnly "Unit.* -jar myjar.jar"
```

Will my tests even be included in the jar when I use the following:

```
sbt dist
```

?

**EDIT**

1. I created a new folder
2. I added `build.sbt` with the following content:

   ```
   name := "abc"

   version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

   scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
   ```
3. I added the `lib` folder and copied my tests jar into it
4. I ran `sbt testOnly Unit.*`
5. It could not find any tests

**EDIT 2**

I tried with the following "proper" SBT file:

```
name := "ihs2tests"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

unmanagedBase in Test := new java.io.File(".")
```

and moved `test.jar` into the root of the project. Again, no tests found.

Comment: This should help get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16409096/2197460.

Comment: Test code is not generally included in `dist` jars, but @DaveSwartz 's link might help with that.

Comment: What about `sbt test:dist`? Wouldn't that include the tests in a (test) dist jar?

Answer (score 1):

> Normally I use sbt testOnly "Unit.*", but that works in the context of a project. I can't find any documentation showing how to do this when there is already a jar.

The `test`-family tasks in SBT (with `testOnly` as an example) work with `compile` task that returns a list of compiled files through an `sbt.inc.Analysis` instance. I couldn't figure out how to amend it and inject the changed Analysis instance to `testOnly` so it knows the test I'm going to run exists.

I'm proposing another solution - **a trick**.

Package the tests classes to a jar with `test:package` task as follows:

```
[test-lib]> test:package
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/test-lib/}test-lib...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/test-lib/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/test-lib/target/scala-2.10/test-lib_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Mar 4, 2014 11:34:13 PM
```

When you have the test jar, you can execute the test framework on the command line **without** SBT (I assume you use ScalaTest given the [scalatest](/questions/tagged/scalatest) tag, but I'll use Specs2). Read the documentation of the test framework on how to do it and for Specs2 it's `specs2.run` as described in [Console output](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#In+the+shell).

Executing tests from the test jar requires defining a proper CLASSPATH that may or may not be easy to get right. That's where SBT can be of great help - to manage dependencies and hence the CLASSPATH.

Create another SBT project and save the test jar in `lib` subdirectory to have it on CLASSPATH (as described in [Unmanaged dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies#unmanaged-dependencies)).

> Dependencies in lib go on all the classpaths (for compile, test, run, and console).

Add a sample `build.sbt` where you define your test framework as a dependency of the project. For Specs2 it's as follows (I used the default configuration as described in [the Specs2 home page](http://specs2.org)):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.8" % "test"

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
```

**The trick** is to execute the main class of the test framework, e.g. `specs2.run` for Specs2, as if the class were executed on the command line. SBT helps with `test:runMain`.

```
[my-another-project]> test:runMain specs2.run HelloWorldSpec
[info] Running specs2.run HelloWorldSpec
HelloWorldSpec

The 'Hello world' string should
+ contain 11 characters
+ start with 'Hello'
+ end with 'world'

Total for specification HelloWorldSpec
Finished in 62 ms
3 examples, 0 failure, 0 error

Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Mar 4, 2014 11:15:14 PM
```

Don't worry about this `Exception` as it comes from SBT that catches `exit` from Specs2 (after test execution) so SBT remains up.

Comment: I copied my build.sbt and tests.jar into a new project but it tried to compile it again so unfortunately that does not work

Comment: Give it a shot again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SBT can't read jar file without any additional/manual setup - I might be wrong but I didn't find anything in the docs. So I tried something like this to make the task simpler:

```
unzip some-test.jar

java -jar sbt-launch.jar \
  'set scalaSource in Test := new java.io.File(".")' \
  'set fullClasspath in Test += Attributed.blank(file("."))' \
  'test'
```

This runs without errors but does not find tests.

If I add `'set includeFilter in (Test, unmanagedSources) := "*Suite*.class"'` to force it to find tests it obviously fails because it expects `*.scala` files, not the compiled `*.class` files.

I'm not an SBT expert, but I think this must be close to a solution. There must be a way to read all files from a jar path programmatically and then tell test framework to use `*.class` files.

At this point is seems more reasonable to run tests using a Scalatest test runner or from sbt using the project.

If you wish to dig deeper take a look at SBT source code and the default `sbt` shell script that does lots of setup before it runs the sbt launcher jar.