# How can I run tests against jar built by sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm running sbt-assembly in order to build a single jar file that can be deployed elsewhere. I would like to run my tests against this jar file rather than against the local .class files. Running against the local .class files is the default with `sbt test` but I want to test the jar instead (but without incorporating the test class files into the jar).

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389446/compile-tests-with-sbt-and-package-them-to-be-run-later.

Comment: @TooTone I'm not sure that Spark is your use case, but maybe it can be interesting to you: http://eugenezhulenev.com/blog/2014/10/18/run-tests-in-standalone-spark-cluster/  I prepared example of running tests in standalone Spark cluster with assembled jar file

Comment: @EugeneZhulenev I will look into that thankyou. It seems it might relate to my question here, also.

Answer (score 1):

To build assembly jar in test you need to configuration

```
import AssemblyKeys._

Project.inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings)

jarName in (Test, assembly) := s"${name.value}-test-${version.value}.jar"
```

So now you can prepare uber-jar with test:assembly. However I don't know easy way to run tests from sbt with this jar. I would go for custom command, something like test:run-test-assembly that will do something like this internally

```
scala -classpath uber-jar-test.jar classpath scalatest-<version>.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -p compiled_tests
```

sbt-assembly is running tests during assembly phase, but I'm pretty sure it's doing it agains not yet packaged classes. Sou you probably want to exclude them from assembly phase with

```
test in (Test, assembly) := {}
```

Comment: thanks but including `scalatest` on the command line seems unnecessary (presumably it gets included automatically when working out the dependencies). And more seriously, when I run `scala -classpath uber-jar-test.jar -classpath org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R target/scala-2.10/test-classes/`, the scalatest GUI pops up and correctly finds my 25 tests, but fails with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` (as the jar is assembled then all the classes ought to be there, right?)

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't answer the question of running tests against an assembly jar; it answers how to build an assembly jar that includes tests.

Comment: This doesn't answer question how to run tests against jar