# Run tests against scala tests jar

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have few smoke tests in my scala service and I want to publish these tests as separate jar (in build pipeline) so that I can run them later after deploying the service (in deployment pipeline). I am using sbt native package and have config enabled for smoke tests. Tests exist in src/main/smoke folder

In build sbt

```
val EndToEndSmoke = config("smoke") extend Test

lazy val project = Project("my-service-name", file("."))
  .configs(EndToEndSmoke)
  .settings(inConfig(EndToEndSmoke)(Defaults.testSettings): _*)
```

I can create tests jar using below command. It creates jar in target\scala-2.12\my-service-name_2.12-0.1-SNAPSHOT-smoke.jar

```
sbt smoke:packageBin
```

Is there any way to run tests against this jar? I tried scalatest runner but it is not doing anything

```
scala -classpath "..\..\..\.ivy2\cache\org.scalatest\scalatest_2.12\bundles\scalatest_2.12-3.0.8.jar;..\..\..\.ivy2\cache\org.scalactic\scalactic_2.12\bundles\scalactic_2.12-3.0.8.jar" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R "targ
et\scala-2.12\smoke-classes"
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile tests with SBT and package them to be run later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389446/compile-tests-with-sbt-and-package-them-to-be-run-later)

Comment: No. I tried those steps. It gives empty window of runner

Comment: @Abhay Did you manage to solve the problem? Could you share ?

Comment: @DangHuyNguyen I didn't find any solution. Later, I used Gatling tool to write tests, packages as jar, published in my pipeline artifact and ran after deployment.